# Canon Pixma MG6850

Tags: canon, scanner, pixma

I bought a Canon Pixma MG6850 all-in-one printer.
I can't get the scanner working.
I use Ubuntu 16.04
The solutions offered by Canon don't work.
Anybody got an idea?

Comment: Have you tried using something like gscan2pdf available from the Ubuntu software centre?

Comment: What are those solutions please share ?

Comment: Thanks Graham, I tried gscan2pdf but it does not work.

Comment: Hi George, I tried the scangear installation with the download from de Canon website. Installation in the terminal.  No luck.